# Pentaho - PAC (Pentaho Administration Console) last version

Tags: pentaho

Does anybody know what is the last version of PAC (Pentaho Administration Console)? I couldn't find the .start-pac.sh from new versions of Pentaho.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PAC no longer exists. Last version was 4.x, I believe. Since 5.0 onwards (most current version is 9.0), you access the admin features by choosing the Administration perspective from the user console (the standard web interface). Of course, you need admin privileges to have access to it.

Perspectives are chosen from the selector near the upper left corner of the window.

Comment: And now some functionalities only has in Enterprise Edition :(. Thanks!